# Electron-positron annihilation to neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics

I was wondering, even though the electron-positron annihilation prefers to give us photons, it can turn into neutrinos as well - as far as I understand. My question is, since the equations I have seen is:

$$\nu \bar{\nu} \leftrightarrow e^{+}e^{-}$$

Do this process only give out electron neutrinos, or can it actually create tau and muon neutrinos as well ?

Energy wise, it makes sense, that it is only electron neutrinos, but neutrinos are always strange imo, so maybe they can do stuff I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron positron annihilations can give mu and tau neutrinos as well as electron neutrinos. For a calculation of the probabilities see for example [Mu and Tau Neutrino Thermalization and Production in Supernovae: Processes and Timescales](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0003054).

You might also be interested to read DavidZ's answer to [Why does electron-positron annihilation prefer to emit photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/why-does-electron-positron-annihilation-prefer-to-emit-photons).

Comment: Ah, great. Just what I needed :)